# from bs4 import Beautifulsoup ImportError: cannot import name 'Beautifulsoup'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/untitled/finder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/untitled/finder.py", line 4, in 
    from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Beautifulsoup'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `Beautifulsoup` --> `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: S must be upperCase ----> `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

you used a lower case s.